# CW-complex with zero boundary operators

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

If I have a CW-complex, is it possible to find a homotopically equivalent one that will have zero boundary operators?

It shouldn't be always possible to find such a triangulation for the initial space (consider two vertices connected with three edges), but I can neither prove the statement above nor find a counterexample.

Comment: What do you mean by *zero boundary operators*? Two spaces which have the same homotopy type have the same homotopy groups.

Comment: @Sigur I was speaking of homology groups. E.g. if I think of a circle as of a CW-complex with 1 vertice and 1 edge, the boundary operators will be zero. And if I think of a circle as of a CW-complex with 2 vertices and 2 edges, that I will have a non-zero boundary operator (though the homologies will not change, obviously).

Comment: So, you start with a CW complex and you'd like to find a CW homotopically equivalent but with all cells being cycles? I believe that it is not possible in general. Let's think about it.

Comment: @Sigur Oh. I suppose that this is impossible even for something as simple as a 2-dimensional disk - and this is easily possible for all 1-dimensional complexes, as they are homotopically equivalent to bundles of circles. Correct?

Comment: Homology groups are not always free, you know...

Comment: Cf. definition of [formal dg-algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/formal+dg-algebra), btw

Comment: @GrigoryM Well yes, that's true. The answer to my question is 'no' with a projective plane being a counterexample.

Comment: @Sigur My statement about a disk was stupid (a disk is homotopic to a point), but the general answer 'no' is explained in Georgy's comment about the groups that may not be free.

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't work because the final step of the argument is not valid.

---

I think the answer is that you can do this if and only if the space has the homotopy type of a wedge of (possibly infinitely many, in different dimensions) spheres. I think the following argument works.

Recall that the differentials $d_n\colon \mathcal C_n\to \mathcal C_{n-1}$ are given by $d_n(e_\alpha^n)=\sum d_{\alpha\beta} e_\beta^{n-1}$ where the $e_\alpha^n$ and $e_\beta^{n-1}$ are the $n$- and $n-1$ cells generating (as free groups) $\mathcal C_n$ and $\mathcal C_{n-1}$.

Hence, the differentials are zero if and only if the $d_{\alpha\beta}$ are zero, but $d_{\alpha\beta}$ is the degree of the inclusion of the boundary of $e_\alpha^n$ into the $n-1$-skeleton $X_{n-1}$ followed by contracting every cell other than $e_\beta^{n-1}$. This is in total a map $S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$, so the degree is just how top homology gets multiplied.

Since maps of degree zero are null-homotopic, you should be able to glue all the null-homotopies together on the CW complex (yay, induction and compactness of spheres) to get that the attaching map itself is null-homotopic (nope, this is blatantly false).

Comment: What about a torus? A torus doesn't seem to be homotopic to a wedge of spheres, but the most obvious CW-complex for a torus (one 2-dimensional cell, two 1-dimensional cells and one 0-dimensional cell) has zero boundary operator.

Comment: You're right, of course.